# Get long number code for high code point characters in js?

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

If for example, I use a long arbitrary number like this one to display a character `String.fromCharCode(123456454545789)` it outputs this character `兽`.

But when I try to retrieve the code of that same character like this     `'兽'.charCodeAt(0);` it outputs this code `20861`.

I understand that `charCodeAt` will always return a value less than 65,536 because chars with  higher code points are represented by a pair of (lower valued) "surrogate" pseudo-characters.

But when I try to get the code of a possible second char by increasing the index like this `'兽'.charCodeAt(1);` there is no further code to return.

If I put that same code in, like this `String.fromCharCode(20861)` it will also show the same character `兽`.

I'm not sure why this happens, maybe its not even meant to happen. But either way, my question is - how can I get that long arbitrary number back? If there are more than one code which can be used to represent that character, like `123456454545789` or `20861` what alternatives/supplements to `charCodeAt` will tell me the former number rather than the latter, for any of those higher code-point characters?

Comment: not sure, but are you aware that 123456454545789 % 65536 is 20861?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The String.fromCharCode() argument is masked to an 16-bit unsigned integer, and this is in accordance with the ECMAScript standard. Thus, when executing String.fromCharCode(123456454545789), the argument is first reduced to 20861. This happens for any argument of the form 20861 + n*65536, so getting the original large number back is impossible (or, to put it formally, you can get an infinite number of such numbers).

This has nothing to do with surrogate code points. The string '兽' consists of one BMP character only. If you have non-BMP character (code number > 0xFFFF), say '' (U+20000), *then* surrogates are relevant, and for such a string (consisting of a single Unicode character internally represented in JavaScript as two surrogate code points), fromCharCode(0) and fromCharCode(1) are defined and yield the surrogate code point values, such as 55360 and 56320. (Modern implementations can usually deal with a literal containing a non-BMP character, like '', though this is not required in the standard.)